# How can I create parallel arrays that hold range of numbers but only few prices in c#

Tags: c#

How can I create parallel arrays as per table below?

```
Meals      | Price each

1-10       | 14.99

11-20      | 12.50

21-39      | 10.75

40 or more | 9.45
```

I tried as below:

```
int[] mealOrder = {1, 2, ....., 40};
decimal[] mealPrice = {14.99M, 12.50M, 10.75M, 9.45M};
```

In my next logic, I need to get the total bills of meals ordered x price per meal. Is there any keyword that I can use to create parallel arrays?

Comment: Academic question? It sounds also like an XY Question.

Comment: The most obvious `List<Tuple<int, int, double>>` (or replace tuple with custom type) to store amount from, amount to and the price. Or simply create a function `PriceForOne(int n)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter 

I tried as below;

int[] mealOrder = {1, 2, ....., 40}
decimal[] mealPrice = {14.99M, 12.50M, 10.75M, 9.45M}

in my next logic, I need to get the total bills of meals ordered x price per meal.

Is there any keyword that I can use to create parallel arrays?

Comment: @TimSchmelter ah ok, so, then I create class for MealOrder & MealPrice?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Ok I got it, Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make independent arrays with data that is not independent.
You will stumble over it with every new extension. Sort, delete, extend, ...

Try something like this:

```
public class MealPrice
{
    public int MealOrders { get; set; }
    public decimal MealPriceEach { get; set; }
}

...

public List<MealPrice> MealPriceList;
```

[edit] better naming

A function for getting the price could be something like this (untested)

```
public decimal GetPrice(int mealOrders)
{
    // ! Error handling missing
    return MealPriceList
        // Get all prices that fit our amount of mealOrders
        .Where(mp => mealOrders >= mp.MealOrders)
        // get the lowest price
        .Min(mp => mp.MealPriceEach);
}
```

Comment: That's mean, I use List<> to hold parallel arrays?

Comment: @tengkuzulfadli I would drop the idea of using parallel arrays. Group related data into a type. Then you can maintain a single list. Like shown in this answer.

Comment: nothing parallel. You have a List of a fixed data structure (MealPrice) that holfs all necessary information of a single item.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the quantities in descending order, then you can use a `Tuple<int, decimal>` and a `List<Tuple<int, decimal>>` to retrieve the price with `Find()` and a lambda:

```
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    List<Tuple<int, decimal>> prices = new List<Tuple<int, decimal>>();
    prices.Add(Tuple.Create(40, 9.45m));
    prices.Add(Tuple.Create(21, 10.75m));
    prices.Add(Tuple.Create(11, 12.50m));
    prices.Add(Tuple.Create(0, 14.99m));

    int quantity = 23;
    decimal price = prices.Find(p => (quantity >= p.Item1)).Item2;
    Console.WriteLine("quantity: " + quantity + " | price: " + price);
  }
```

Comment: If you don't like using `Tuple`, then create a struct/class as suggested by Klamsi.  The setup and code will be very similar.